# CSV ORDER GROUP

Tags: c#, array, csv

Buenas tengo una entrada csv de esta forma

```
id,apellido,email,genero,talla,precio
```

Lo cual necesito saber: El tamaño de camiseta que mas ganancias reportó y su valor (en dinero)

Lo que me produce un error de que al aumentar el precio no puedo porque no la tengo asociada a ninguna valor, tome la talla como key, si existe se le suma el valor de esa camiseta si no, se crea y se le agrega el valor del precio.
Pero como decía no me deja ocupar el var precio = p.Split(',')[5].Split('$')[1], ya que no esta en el diccionario, ¿alguna solución o consejo?

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

```
List<Tipovalor> listaCamisetas = new List<Tipovalor>();


        foreach (var linea in lineas)
        {
            var camposSeparados = linea.Split(',');
            listaCamisetas.Add(new Tipovalor
            {
                Camiseta = camposSeparados[4],
                Valor = decimal.Parse(camposSeparados[5].Replace("$", string.Empty), CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
            });
        }

        var consulta = listaCamisetas.GroupBy(l => l.Camiseta)
            .Select(x => x)
```

Me perdí en el orderby

Comment: Te recomiendo primero que crees una pequeña clase para almacenar los datos del tamaño y del precio y que te crees una lista rellenándola en el ´for´. No utilices ´Split´ varias veces cuando lo puedes hacer una sola guardándolo en un ´array´. Luego utiliza LinQ con el listado, puedes hacer una agrupación por tallas ´group by´, obteniendo a la vez la suma de los precios y luego mediante un ´order by´ y un ´last´ obtener la talla que más ha recaudado. Inténtalo, pon aquí tus resultados, y si no lo consigues te dejo el código que lo hace.

Comment: Lo intentaré!, cualquier cosa te digo como me va!

Comment: @JuanRu Actualizado a ver si me puedes ayudar con el orderby

Comment: Buen esfuerzo, te ha faltado un detalle, te dejo mi respuesta detallada, espero que te guste

Comment: Gracias a los dos!, se pasaron!!

Comment: ¿Por qué quitaste el código?

Comment: UPDATE!, ahora si está! @Aprendiz

Comment: no coloques solucionado al título de tu pregunta, lo borré, con marcar la respuesta que te sirvió como aceptada alcanza

Comment: No sabía soy nuevo aún, pero gracias por ayudarme a borrar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo la solución que te había propuesto en los comentarios:

Primero me he inventado esta clase:

```
public class TipoCamisetaValor
{
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Luego he tratado el string del CSV capturado:

```
public TipoCamisetaValor ObtenerMayorValorPorCamiseta(string csv)
{
    TipoCamisetaValor resultado = null;

    // Se crea una colección por líneas recuperadas del CSV
    ICollection<string> lineas = csv.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    List<TipoCamisetaValor> listaCamisetas = new List<TipoCamisetaValor>();

    // Recoges los resultados en el listado por cada línea del CSV
    foreach (var linea in lineas)
    {
        var camposSeparados = linea.Split(',');
        listaCamisetas.Add(new TipoCamisetaValor
        {
            Tipo = camposSeparados[4],
            Valor = decimal.Parse(camposSeparados[5].Replace("$", string.Empty), CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
        });
    }

    // Analizas el resultado con LinQ agrupando por tamaño de camiseta
    // Seleccionas la camiseta y el sumatorio de los precios agrupados
    // Ordenas de menor a mayor y eliges el último... o al revés
    var consulta = listaCamisetas.GroupBy(l => l.Tipo)
        .Select(x => new TipoCamisetaValor { Tipo = x.Key, Valor = x.Sum(y => y.Valor) })
        .OrderBy(l => l.Valor).Last();

    return resultado;
}
```

Lo medio tenías, has tratado el `order by` correctamente pero te ha faltado tratar las filas agrupadas, sólo agrupaste por talla, después del `group by` debías hacer una `select` tal y como te he puesto en el código, es lo único que te faltaba por así decirlo.

```
.Select(x => new TipoCamisetaValor { Tipo = x.Key, Valor = x.Sum(y => y.Valor) })
```

Luego me he tomado la libertad de poner cómo haría la separación de líneas mediante `Split`, no es que sea ni mejor ni peor que `File.ReadAllLines`, tan sólo me he abstraido de la forma de obtener el CSV:

```
ICollection<string> lineas = csv.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Y para eliminar el caracter '$' creo que es mejor hacer un `Replace`.

Si tienes dudas dímelo, espero que sea lo que buscabas.

Answer (score 1):

El `linq` pareciera estar correcto, pero no entiendo el porque del `where parts.Length == 2` eso esta de mas

La primer parte podría ser

```
var lineas = File.ReadAllLines("MOCK_DATA.csv");


List<Ganaciayvalor> data = (from p in lineas
                           let parts = p.Split(',')
                           select new Ganaciayvalor()
                           {
                               talla = parts[4],
                               valor = Convert.ToDecimal(parts[5].Replace("$", ""))
                           }).ToList();
```

Algunos puntos

- entiendo la clase `Ganaciayvalor` la tienes definida con dos propiedades
- no haces un *split* del $, sino que lo quitas
- las posiciones que debes tomar son las 4 y 5, no se porque tomaste las dos primeras

Despues continuas agrupando

```
var result = from item in data
                group item by item.talla into g
                select new 
                {
                    talla = g.Key,
                    total = g.Sum(x=>x.valor)
                };
```

Aquí si quieres puede usar la misma `class` que tenias o usar otra, en el ejemplo sera una anónima